# Why does the vector.size() function give me an error?

Tags: c++, vector, lambda

When I try to use vector.size() , it gives me the following errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
[Error] expected unqualified-id before '(' token
[Error] expected primary-expression before ')' token
[Error] lambda-expression in unevaluated context
[Error] expected identifier before numeric constant
In lambda function:
[Error] expected '{' before ')' token
```

The rest of the vector functions work. I've used this function before and It worked, now I can't use it.

here's the code:

```
while(1)
{
    vector<string> frase;
    string stringa;
    getline(cin,stringa);
    {
           string temp;
           temp.clear();
           for(int i=0;i<stringa.length();i++)
           {
                if(stringa[i]!=' ')temp+=stringa[i];
                else
                {
                    frase.push_back(temp);
                    temp.clear();
                 }
           }
           frase.push_back(temp);
    }


    analizza(frase.data(), /*ERROR HERE*/ frase.size() /*ERROR HERE*/);

           frase.clear();


    for(int i=0;i<frase.size();i++)frase.pop_back();
}
```

what can I do?

Comment: Is it fair to assume you are using the `std::string` class? And `std::vector`, for that matter?

Comment: Yes, I am. Also I've included <string> and <vector>

Comment: You should make sure you specify which line the error is on, but this looks wrong: `string parole[frase.size()];` You can't declare an array with a non-const.

Comment: Now I've cleared up. How can I declare it using the size of the vector, then? Is there a way?

Comment: I'm also concerned about `temp+=stringa[i];`. Is `temp` supposed to be a pointer?

Comment: No, It is used to store the letters until I find a blank space, add temp to the vector, and then start over. I use this code to divide a string into a vector of words. But that's not the problem...

Comment: +1 to what @crashmstr said. If you want an array of strings, try using `string* parole = new string[size]`

Comment: @Infinitesimus No, use `std::vector<std::string>`. Why go through all the pain of manual memory management when the standard library does it for you?

Comment: You are missing a bunch of relevant headers. Post a small test-case.

Comment: What is the definition of the function `analizza`?

Comment: @Angew Good point :P. I've been spoiled by the .NET world when it comes to thinking about memory management :(

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to declare an array with a runtime size here:

```
string parole[frase.size()];
```

C++ doesn't support that. It seems that your compiler is interepreting that as a lambda expression instead.

You don't need an array at all - just use `frase`. Or, if your function really needs to take a pointer as input, use `frase.data()`:

```
while(1)
{
    vector<string> frase;
    string stringa;
    getline(cin,stringa);
    {
        //same as before
    }

    analizza(frase.data(), frase.size());

    frase.clear();
}
```

Comment: it gives me the same errors.

Comment: @NetHacker It can't give the exact same errors, because the offending line is not present in my code. Perhaps you could edit the question and add the *exact* line of the error. I mean, mark it in the code with a comment or something. An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would be even better; something we could copy&paste to e.g. [ideone](http://ideone.com/) and see the error ourselves.

Comment: So I need to paste the whole code?

Comment: @NetHacker No, you need to post a test case. See sscce.org

Comment: @NetHacker No. Paste a *minimal* thing we could build. For all I know, it could be caused by a weird prototype of `analizza`.

Comment: Ok I have a little problem. I've winded it down to a minimal thing, and now it works. The main function is basically the same. What do I do?

Comment: @NetHacker That's why you should *always* prepare a test case *first,* before posting on SO. It appears the problem was somewhere else; keep adding stuff back until you find it, and perhaps you'll understand the problem then. If not, ask about it, with a minimal test case included.

Comment: The source code is now the same as the full case and it works. I don't know why. Do I need to close the question?

Comment: @NetHacker I'd probably move to close it as "can no longer be reproduced" if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues with your code overall:

**Parsing**

```
string stringa;
getline(cin,stringa);
{
       string temp;
       temp.clear();
       for(int i=0;i<stringa.length();i++)
       {
            if(stringa[i]!=' ')temp+=stringa[i];
            else
            {
                frase.push_back(temp);
                temp.clear();
             }
       }
       frase.push_back(temp);
}
```

That block of code is completely unnecessary.  The entire logic can be accomplished like so:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> start(iss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> v(start, end);
```

**Variable Length Arrays**

VLAs are not standard (some compilers have them as an extension, but this is **not** portable).  The following code will not compile on a standard compiler:

```
string parole[frase.size()];
```

Instead, if you want an array of indeterminate size, you use `std::vector` (which you already have, so there is no need to do anything).  If the function you are attempting to call needs a pointer, you can use `v.data()` (if you are using a compiler that supports C++11) or `&v[0]` (if you need to compile under the C++03 standard).

Comment: Ok, I understand the part about the VLAs. I don't exactly understand the part before, it creates a vector with the line's words (no spaces)? I've never seen istrinstream and iss().

Comment: @NetHacker You are just writing far more code than you need to in order to accomplish your goal.  `std::istream` will parse strings delimited by whitespace using `operator>>` (just like you do with `std::cin`).  `std::istringstream` allows you to supply a `std::string` to be treated as a `std::istream` (which I named `iss`, but can be any valid name).  The iterator declarations are just to give the starting point and ending point for the `std::vector`'s [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) (overload #3) that takes iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of strings instead of a vector you'd have to use char[] or char* and allocate dynamically. You can't create an array size with a variable.

Comment: No, he could use `std::string* = new std::string[v.size()]`, but `std::vector<std::string>` is the superior approach.  If he wasn't going to use any standard classes, it would be a `char**`, not a `char*`.